# Installing the SSRS Data Connector for CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have installed Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, Update roll-up 14 in my VPC.
While I try to install Microsoft Dynamic CRM Reporting Extensions using SetupSrsDataConnector.exe, I get an error saying,

> *Setup cannot proceed because an error occurred while copying installer files to the local system: The upgrade cannot be installed
>   by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded
>   may be missing, or the upgrade may update a different version of the
>   program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your
>   computer and that you have the correct upgrade For additional details
>   see logfile.*

Does anyone know what is wrong? I tried several instances but they all don't work either. I can access my SSRS server by going to http: //SSRS-Server/Reports and it will give a list of all services running there.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some more details about you server setup? Are you trying to install this on CRM server or SQL server? Are you sure the reporting extension is for 2011? Do run an update if it is available.

Comment: Were you ever able to install the software?

Answer (score 0):

Is there enough disk space for the installation?

Are you installing the update on the SQL machine or the CRM machine?

Are you installing the correct version? CRM 2011, CRM 2013? 64bit, 32bit?

Could you post the results from the log file?

```
C:\Users\<LoginName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MSCRM\Logs
```